# Import Springframework source code in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

> Mac OSX Catalina
>
> JDK: 1.8.0_191
>
> IDE: IDEA 2019.2.4

**Step 1:** I cloned the latest code from Github repo: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework.git.

**Step 2:** Then follow the guidelines of https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/import-into-idea.md

After all the operations, still got import errors in the IDE:
[image: import error]
I checked the source code files, all the files are there.

Also, I checked this post: [springframework source in Idea Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867690/springframework-source-in-idea-intellij) But it seems not relevant to mine.

**Note:** If I run `./gradlew build`, no errors happened in the command line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), where we should be able to *copy and paste* your code *in text* into our compiler and run it.

Comment: The code is in the spring official Github repo, everyone has access to it. You can follow the steps I provided.

Comment: I would ask that you post it directly here, I do believe there was a question discouraging posting lines of code as images. One of the reasons was because some people used mobile data and images are heavy.

Comment: could you please try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952078/intellij-cannot-resolve-symbol-on-import and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207108385-IntelliJ-not-able-to-resolve-classes-of-external-Libraries-for-Maven-projects

Comment: Good to hear it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @anshul suggest in the comments, this post helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27508764/3049524

In the IntelliJ IDEA, choose this menu, after the restart, it works.

**File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart**